# how to make conda python packages use a local c library?

Tags: conda

I am using [OpenSlide Python](https://github.com/openslide/openslide-python) installed to my Conda environment to process svs files. At some point, my script returned an OpenJPEG error which [seems to be caused](https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/issues/179) by some bug in an older version of OpenJPEG C library installed on the cluster (v1.5.1).

To solve this, I installed the latest OpenJPEG to my Conda environment (using `conda install`) since I didn't do it before. `conda list` now returns:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
...
openjpeg                  2.3.1                h981e76c_3    conda-forge
openslide-python          1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
...
```

but the problem persists.

So I'm wondering if the reason is that OpenSlide still uses the older OpenJPEG and not the new local one. How can I check which version is used and make OpenSlide use the right one?

Comment: If you compiled `openslide-python` yourself, chances are good you need to recompile. I think a reinstall with pip should do. You can check which library gets loaded by locating the the relevant `.so` files in the `lib/pythonx.y/site-packages` directory of the interpreter and run `ldd <path-to-.so-file`. This should show the path to the library that gets loaded to satisfy the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem by deleting `openslide-python` and reinstalling it using `conda install` instead of `pip` (which I used before). I guess the problem was that packages installed by `pip` and `conda` may conflict with each other and/or not recognise each other, so openslide didn't recognise new `openjpeg` installed using conda.